# CircleCI ignoring specified cypress version and reverting to previous

Tags: docker, cypress, circleci

Context:-

We have a Vue UI + Rails API running in circleCI, and have a custom docker image for running our cypress tests in, which has cypress pre-installed.

We previously used cypress 8.4.1, but have now bumped to 10.2.0.

There is no reference to v8.4.1 anywhere in our package.json, so my theory is that it's being cached somewhere, but I've no idea how.

**Dockerfile for cypress_testing image where we pre-install cypress:-**

```
# copy these two files so we can add cypress
COPY --chown=circleci package.json package.json // specified at 10.2.0 in here
COPY --chown=circleci package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm i
RUN npx cypress install
```

**package.json referred to above**

```
{
  "name": "cypress_testing",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "cypress": "~10.2.0"
  }
}
```

**config.yml file for circleCI**

```
jobs:
  build_api:
    <<: *ui_defaults
    docker:
      - image: mycompany/cypress_testing
        environment:
          PYTHON: /usr/bin/python2.7
          RAILS_ENV: development
    
  - image: circleci/postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: circleci

working_directory: ~/my-app

steps:
  - add_ssh_keys:
      fingerprints:
        - "1234"

  - run:
      name: Git clone api repository
      command: |
        cd ~
        git clone git@github.com:my-company/my-app
        cd my-app
        git checkout origin/develop 

  - run:
      name: copy Gemfile.lock to working_directory
      command: |
        cp /home/circleci/my-app/app/Gemfile.lock /home/circleci/my-app/Gemfile.lock

  # Download and cache dependencies
  - restore_cache:
      paths:
        - ~/my-app/app/vendor/bundle
      keys:
        - v2-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
        # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
        - v2-dependencies-

  - run:
      name: install dependencies
      working_directory: app
      command: bundle install --jobs=4 --retry=3

  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ~/my-app/app/vendor/bundle
      key: v2-dependencies-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}

  # Database setup
  - run:
      name: set up database
      working_directory: app
      command: |
        bundle exec rails db:create
        bundle exec rails db:migrate

  - run:
      name: Run API
      command: |
        cd ~/my-app/app
        bundle exec rails s -p 3001
      background: true

  - attach_workspace:
      at: ~/app

  - run:
      name: Start Vue.js server
      command: |
        cd ~/app
        npm rebuild node-sass
        npm run serve
      background: true

  - run:
      name: Wait for Vue.js server to be up
      shell: /bin/sh
      command: |
        wget --retry-connrefused --waitretry=60 --read-timeout=5 --timeout=15 -t 30 http://localhost:8080
        :

  - run:
      name: Run Cypress Tests
      command: |
        cd ~/app
        npx cypress@10.3.0 install --force
        npx cypress run
```

workflows:
version: 2
build_and_test:
jobs:
- build_and_test_ui
- build_api:
requires:
- build_and_test_ui

So, we have specified 10.2.0 in our package.json in our custom docker image.  When I SSH into this container in our pipeline, it tells me that version 8.4.1 is installed (this was our previous version):-

```
circleci@47df55b52ad8:~/app$ npx cypress --version
Cypress package version: 8.4.1
Cypress binary version: not installed
Electron version: not found
Bundled Node version: not found
```

I also check the version specified in package.json in our container - still 10.2.0.

So, in an attempt to try to override this, I added the line you can see at the end of the config.yml:-

```
npx cypress@10.3.0 install --force
```

This logs the following, in circleCI (It says installing 10.2.0, outputs a ton of random crap, and then says installing cypress 8.4.1??):-

```
npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: cypress@10.2.0
[..................] \ idealTree:cypress: sill placeDep ROOT cypress@10.3.0 OK[[K..................] \ idealTree:cypress: sill placeDep ROOT cypress@10.3.0 OK[[K..................] \ idealTree:cypress: sill placeDep ROOT cypress@10.3.0 OK[[K..................] | idealTree:cypress: sill placeDep ROOT cypress@10.3.0 OK[[K..................] | idealTree:cypress: sill placeDep ROOT cypress@10.3.0 OK[[K     .............] / idealTree:yauzl: sill fetch manifest rimraf@^3.0.0[[K     .............] | idealTree:yauzl: sill fetch manifest rimraf@^3.0.0[[K     .............] \ idealTree:yauzl: sill fetch manifest rimraf@^3.0.0[[K     .............] | idealTree:yauzl: sill fetch manifest rimraf@^3.0.0[[K..................] - idealTree:uuid: sill fetch manifest punycode@^2.1.1[[K..................] | idealTree:uuid: sill fetch manifest punycode@^2.1.1[[K  ................] | idealTree:supports-color: sill fetch manifest color-conv[[K   ...............] - idealTree:string-width: sill placeDep ROOT string-width@[[K    ..............] / idealTree:strip-final-newline: sill fetch manifest mimic[[K    ..............] | idealTree:which: sill fetch manifest shebang-regex@^3.0.[[K    ..............] / idealTree:pump: sill placeDep ROOT pump@3.0.0 OK for: ge[[K     .............] - idealTree:sshpk: sill fetch manifest verror@1.10.0[[K     .............] | idealTree:sshpk: sill fetch manifest verror@1.10.0[[K     .............] \ idealTree:is-path-inside: sill fetch manifest ini@2.0.0[[K      ............] - idealTree:wrap-ansi: sill fetch manifest tslib@^2.1.0[[K      ............] / idealTree:wrap-ansi: sill fetch manifest tslib@^2.1.0[[K      ............] / idealTree:wrap-ansi: sill fetch manifest type-fest@^0.21
[      ............] \ idealTree:aggregate-error: sill placeDep ROOT aggregate-[[K       ...........] \ idealTree:once: sill placeDep ROOT once@1.4.0 OK for: pu[[K        ..........] - idealTree:strip-ansi: sill placeDep ROOT strip-ansi@6.0.[[K        ..........] | idealTree:rimraf: sill placeDep ROOT rimraf@3.0.2 OK for[[K        ..........] | idealTree:glob: sill placeDep ROOT glob@7.2.3 OK for: ri[[K        ..........] | idealTree:path-is-absolute: sill fetch manifest brace-ex[[K         .........] / idealTree:fd-slicer: sill placeDep ROOT fd-slicer@1.1.0[[K         .........] - idealTree: timing idealTree Completed in 1679ms[[K         .........] | reify:cypress: timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms[[K         .........] - reify:cypress: timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms
[         .........] - reify:cypress: timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms[[K         .........] - reify:cypress: timing reify:loadBundles Completed in 0ms[[K             .....] | reify:getpass: timing reifyNode:node_modules/minimatch C[[K                 .] / reify:tweetnacl: timing reifyNode:node_modules/performan[[K                 .] \ reify:sshpk: timing reifyNode:node_modules/semver Comple[[K                  ] - reify:@types/node: timing reifyNode:node_modules/listr2[[K                  ] | reify:common-tags: timing reifyNode:node_modules/async C
[                  ] | reify:common-tags: timing reifyNode:node_modules/async C[[K                  ] / reify:dayjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/common-tags C[[K                  ] / reify:dayjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/common-tags C[[K                  ] / reify:dayjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/common-tags C[[K                  ] / reify:dayjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/common-tags C[[K                  ] | reify:cypress: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs[[K                  ] | reify:cypress: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs[[K                  ] | reify:cypress: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple[[K                  ] - reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple
[                  ] / reify:rxjs: timing reifyNode:node_modules/cypress Comple

Installing Cypress (version: 8.4.1)
```

Does anyone know where this 8.4.1 may be coming from?